# Dataframe in pandas synthax error about the :

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax-error, naming

I do have a problem in the start if my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


V1 = pd.read_excel('S1V1.xlsx', skiprows=9, parse_dates=[['Date','Time']])
V2 = pd.read_excel('S1V2.xlsx', skiprows=9, parse_dates=[['Date','Time']])

V1V2=pd.DataFrame({V1['Date_Time'],'S1V1':V1['TEMPERATURE'],'S1V2':V2['TEMPERATURE']})
```

When I'm running it, it says that I have a `SynthaxError: invalid syntax` over the `'S1V2':V2['TEMPERATURE']` especially pointing the `:`.

I'm really don't see my mistake. Is there anyone who sees it ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks ! It was that easy ! I thought that if I didn't want to rename I just needed to refer to the column I wanted.

Comment: You are welcome. Since the solution worked, please accept the answer so that this question can be closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the column name of for the first column (`V1['Date_Time']`):

Try:

```
V1V2=pd.DataFrame({'Date_Time':V1['Date_Time'],'S1V1':V1['TEMPERATURE'],'S1V2':V2['TEMPERATURE']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `pd.merge`:

```
V1V2 = pd.merge(V1, V2, on='date_time', how='left')
```

The `on` argument needs to be a common column (might be 'date_time', the index...)